# Getting text from between Tags in XML using jSoup

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, jsoup

Im trying to get the value of `<report_id>` from the following statement

```
<start_task_response status_text="OK, request submitted" status="202"><report_id>524291e2-bde8-4cd8-b48b-59a38f347ff2</report_id></start_task_response>
```

I have tried using the following code but it doesn't seem to want to work?

Any help would be gratefully received.

```
String taskid = Jsoup.parse(input).getAllElements().tagName(report_id);
```

or

```
String taskid = Jsoup.parse(input).getAllElements().attr("report_id");
```

Thanks

EDIT: Ok, as asked below; I will update with the response included from the below solution. Here is my (working) code now...

```
         Elements elms = Jsoup.parse(input).select("start_task_response report_id");
   for (Element e : elms){
   String taskid = e.text();
   jTextField6.setText(taskid);
   System.out.println(taskid);
```

This still does not return anything into String taskid. I have also tried modifying the

```
("start_task_response report_id")
```

to

```
("report_id")
```

Any further help would be appreciated

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine for me. Check http://pastebin.com/EjjSm9qL

Comment: Yes, i tried the code and it works. Are your `import`s right? (i.e. are you `import`ing the classes `org.jsoup.nodes.Element` and `org.jsoup.selects.Elements`?

Comment: @Pshemo I was referring to Remotejon ;)

Comment: @user2340612 Sorry, my bad :) Mistook you with OP.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I fiddled and now it works - :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
Elements elems = JSoup.parse(...).select("start_task_response report_id");
for (Element e : elems) {
    String txt = e.text();
}
```

You can choose between `text()` and `ownText()` methods. The difference is the following:

> For example, given HTML < p >Hello < b >there< /b > now!< /p >, p.ownText() returns "Hello now!", whereas p.text() returns "Hello there now!". Note that the text within the b element is not returned, as it is not a direct child of the p element

Comment: It's not a complete stack trace..what is the line that gives you the error?

Comment: @Remotejon Don't post errors in comments. Edit your original question and include it there. Also don't forget to add code used to create error.

Comment: My bad - Im new Sorry!